# How to Use preg_replace for multiple consecutive spaces

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to test a string for multiple, consecutive spaces and replace them with a `<br>`.

I'm trying to let a user magically put a `<br>` in a string by using two spaces, which would then be added to the table with `<br>` instead of the two spaces.

I've tried a number of preg_replace combinations but don't seem to get it quite right.

```
    $value = preg_replace('/\s+\s+/','<br>',$value);
    $value = preg_replace('/\s+\','<br>',$value);
    $value = preg_replace('/\s++/','<br>',$value);
```

Obviously I'm not very good with preg_replace, can someone please offer a solution?

Comment: What's wrong with just `preg_replace('/  /','<br>',$value);`

Comment: Please don't use regex for parsing HTML.  Use an HTML parser.

Comment: Well [your first regex should work](https://3v4l.org/rYG6A), though it's a weird way of writing `/\s{2,}/`. The other ones are invalid/don't make sense tho.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php https://regex101.com/

Comment: @miken32 The only thing wrong with it is I didn't think of it. I tried your very simple and clear idea/question and works perfectly in all the situations I'm worried about. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple example I have @miken32 answer was spot on.

```
$value = preg_replace('/  /','<br>',$value);
```

Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace 2 spaces, you might also use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
echo str_replace("  ", " ", $value);
```

If you want to use a regex, you might use `\h{2}` to match 2 horizontal whitespace characters

```
$value = "Two  spaces and one space and three   spaces and ten          spaces";
echo preg_replace('/\h{2}/', '<br>', $value);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/3O6iT)